# Graphics card overheating

Tags: graphics-card, overheating

So I figure my GPU is dying,  I've had my GTX 550Ti by Zotac for a little over three years so I'm buying a new gpu next week. I bought a new case because I thought the GPU was overheating due to the confined air circulation in the previous case.

Turns out I was wrong,  even with my new N400 case by coolermaster, my card will still run at 100 degrees and will actually force my PC to shut off during stress. What can the reasons be? I've done a thorough cleaning of the GPU (did not replace the thermal paste) and not to mention the rest of the PC.

Comment: You didn't replace the thermal paste; it's over heating; so replace the thermal paste and verify the fan is working to its specifications

Comment: How exactly did you clean the GPU? Did you remove the heatsink? Did you have the problem before you attempted to clean the GPU? Does the fan spin normally?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz cleaned it with a can of compressed air, I did remove the heatsink, the fan appears to be spinning fine and maxes at 74 percent. I figure Ramhound is most likely correct, it probably is the thermal paste, factory applied thermal paste sometimes cracks and dries over time

Comment: @AngeloCassinelli It works just fine when it's cracked and dried, so long as you don't remove the heatsink. But you removed the heatsink without replacing the thermal paste. That's probably the issue. Once it's dried and cracked, it can't flow anymore.

Comment: 100 degrees is fine for a GPU with correct thermal paste application (ie not removed after drying), what other temperatures are you seeing on your system?  Also it would be good to state F or C...

Comment: @cpt_fink Once it gets above 100 degrees,  the PC automatically turns off. I got 101 yesterday for a second

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I realized that I said I removed the heatsink, sorry, I didn't remove the heatsink, I cleaned under it, around it,  inside of it,  but I didnt unscrew the heatsink at any point. It was overheating before I decided to clean it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for thermal paste.**

It is applied between processor and head sink so that the heat radiated by the processor is rapidly transferred to the heat sink, where the heat from heat sink is cooled by the air circulation by the cooler fan.

So, in your case the thermal paste is missing which brings a gap in transferring the heat from to heat sink. resulting the processor getting overheated.

I would suggest you to apply a layer of thermal paste between your processor and heatsink and check if that works.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Note OP's new(er) edit: "I realized that I said I removed the heatsink, sorry, I didn't remove the heatsink, "